# ApplicationVariant, BaseVariantOutput are Deprecated

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using the following simplified configuration in a Kotlin Dsl file in an Android application project.

```
    class ApplicationVariantAction : Action<ApplicationVariant> {
    override fun execute(variant: ApplicationVariant) {
        val fileName = createFileName(variant)
        variant.outputs.all(VariantOutputAction(fileName))
    }

    private fun createFileName(variant: ApplicationVariant): String {
        return "Android" +
                "_${variant.name}" +
                "_${variant.flavorName}" +
                "_${variant.buildType}" +
                "_${variant.versionName}" +
                "_${variant.versionCode}" +
                "_${getDateTimeFormat()}.apk"
    }

    private fun getDateTimeFormat(): String {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyMdHms", Locale.US)
        return simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
    }

    class VariantOutputAction(
        private val fileName: String
    ) : Action<BaseVariantOutput> {
        override fun execute(output: BaseVariantOutput) {
            if (output is BaseVariantOutputImpl) {
                output.outputFileName = fileName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But AS gives me that ApplicationVariant, and BaseVariantOutput are deprecated

How can I replace these deprecated classes?

Answer (score 6):

The **Variant API** available
in **`com.android.build.gradle.api`** package
in **`com.android.tools.build:gradle`** artifact
has been deprecated.

> That includes `BaseVariant` and all of its direct and indirect subclasses:
> `LibraryVariant`, `ApkVariant`, `ApplicationVariant`, `FeatureVariant`, `TestVariant`, `UnitTestVariant`.

The new Variant API is available
in **`com.android.build.api.variant`** package
in **`com.android.tools.build:gradle-api`** artifact.

> When writing plugins, it is now recommended to depend on only the `gradle-api` artifact in order to use only the new interfaces and classes. One small exception here is the plugin classes that will move to `gradle-api` in 8.0:
>
> - `AppPlugin`
> - `LibraryPlugin`
> - `DynamicFeaturePlugin`
> - `TestPlugin`

See [Android Gradle Plugin DSL/API migration timeline](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-roadmap#agp_80_mid-2022) for migration details and
[New APIs in the Android Gradle Plugin](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/new-apis-in-the-android-gradle-plugin-f5325742e614) for a great write-up about the API changes.